# Attacks on Full TripleDES

Tags: 3des, attack

I have been reading about attacks and many of them work on specific rounds of TripleDES but not on full TripleDES. Is there any attack except brute force that works on full TripleDES? (theoretical)

Comment: Why don't you provide your list? Maybe even as a community wiki answer, so that other can contribute.

Comment: no contribution at all!!! Is their something wrong with the question?

Comment: I voted to close as too broad. At the very least you should limit it to one or the other. Something like "what is the currently best (theoretical) attack on AES" could be OK. (Possibly ruling out related-key attacks if you don't find them to be very interesting.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  I think now I  should edit it or delete it. But please don't close it.